# Acumatica: How to use Report Designer to create table lines

Tags: report, acumatica, designer

i am trying to figure out if there is an eas way to create table lines.
I tried working with panels, but experienced issues with them not always growing with the textbox, which made it problematic. Is there any good way to do it?

I already tried the things mentioned in this topic, but couldn't achieve the goal: https://community.acumatica.com/reports-and-generic-inquires-83/how-to-create-a-table-in-a-report-79
The line always didnt go through all sections.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a screenshot of the report designer and a screenshot of the resulting report? That will make it easier to determine what might be wrong.

Comment: Hej.

I followed the guideline here: https://community.acumatica.com/reports-and-generic-inquires-83/how-to-create-a-table-in-a-report-79


The Behavior is similar to this: https://imgur.com/a/NTRX5V3
It seems not to work with growing textboxes. We have the certain possibility that a textbox needs to be able to grow and if a textbox within a detailsection grows, the line doesnt appear to grow with it. We always had spaces inbetween. 
Not really visually appealing.

Comment: I see that. Is it one solid line through the whole report?

Comment: The lines goes from the groupheadersection to the groupfootersection.
I thought the line would grow if a detailsection grows, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the height of each cell in the grid, so that if text wrapped to the next line it would still be within the height of the cell.

If you have a huge disparity between possible text lengths in each cell, this may work less well.